# Wordpress: Getting an php Array into JS-Function

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, wordpress, variables

I would like to use a PHP Array, that I’m retrieving in the WP-Loop into a javascript function, that I’m having in a separate js-file.

That’s how I’m echoing my php array (from Advanced Custom Fields) in the loop:

```
$images = get_field('galerie');
if( $images ): ?>
    <?php 
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $images as $image ): 
        $i++;
        ?>
        <div class="slider">
             <?php echo $image['url']; ?>');">
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In the final code this would look like:

```
<div class="slider">   
   THERE_GOES_THE_IMG_URL_1 
   THERE_GOES_THE_IMG_URL_2 
   THERE_GOES_THE_IMG_URL_3
</div>
```

But I need to use the Image URLs in my Vegas Slider JQuery Plugin. The code is in a separate custom.js file and looks like this:

```
$(".slider").vegas({
      slides: [
          { src: "THERE_GOES_THE_IMG_URL_1" },
          { src: "THERE_GOES_THE_IMG_URL_2" },
          { src: "THERE_GOES_THE_IMG_URL_3" }
      ]
  });
```

How can I pass the Image URLs from the php loop into the jQuery Plugin?

Thanks for your help!
Cara

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the structure of your array but you can use `json_encode($images)` and pass the data in a JS variable using `wp_localize_script`. So in functions.php you do this:

```
$images = get_field('galerie');
$images = json_encode($images);

wp_enqueue_script( 'my_js_file', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js' );
$data_to_send = array(
    'images' => $images
);
wp_localize_script( 'my_js_file', 'object_name', $data_to_send );
```

And then in your javascript file `custom.js` you can get what you need like this:

```
var my_images = JSON.parse(object_name.images);
var imagesToAppend = [];
for(var i = 0; i < my_images.length; i++){
    var img_src = my_images[i].url;
    imagesToAppend[i] = { src: img_src };
}
console.log(imagesToAppend);
$(".slider").vegas({
      slides: imagesToAppend
  });
```

Notice that you have to parse the response string using `JSON.parse`.

A simplified solution would be to change the name of the `url` to `src` from ACF so you don't have to use that loop and change the keys for the object to `src` and then you can just append `my_images` to the Vegas slider init, like this:

```
var my_images = JSON.parse(object_name.images);
$(".slider").vegas({
  slides: my_images
});
```

Also, if you're including the `custom.js` script in other way then I exemplified above, please remove that, or you will get the same response twice.

It really depends on your array structure, but this should work.

Also, you can read more about `wp_localize_script` **[here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)**.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ionut. Your solution worked perfectly for me! Already implented and no errors! Really great!

Comment: @CaraMar, awesome. I'm glad it worked. Happy to help.